# Gedit UI different if I run gksu: Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome Classic

Tags: unity, gedit, gnome-classic

Something strange which I'm trying to understand:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Gnome Classic

If I launch gedit from the **menu** or **command line** as myself, I get the following UI:

[image: SCREENSHOT 1: gedit as user]

^ this one has:

- the menu bar at the top of the window
- with the [ Open ] and [ + ] and [ Save ] directly underneath

However, if I launch gedit from the **command line** using gksu gedit, I get a different looking UI:

[image: SCREENSHOT 2: gedit using gksu]

^ this one has:

- the [ Open ] and [ + ] and [ Save ] in the title bar at the top of the window
- with the menu bar directly underneath

---

Now I know that the *sudo* profile is different to my *user* profile, but I can't work out what is changing.

Is the gksu gedit using a Unity desktop view - as opposed to my user view as Gnome classic ?

I have searched around a bit, and am having no luck working it out.

Any advice ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT** *additional info*

I logged out of Gnome Classic and logged back in using Unity ... and got a similar display to the first screenshot.

I am still trying to work out how to get the second view while launching as a normal user.

Comment: It looks like you're launching two different versions of Gedit: the old Unity version and then the new GNOME version,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difference is being made to maintain compatibility between Unity's global menu and Gnome's menu style, I believe.

After searching the differences between root and normal user's shell, I found that normal user has `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable set to `GNOME-Flashback:Unity`.

So, If you want to the UI of gedit like the root, you need to use this command or unset the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable.

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='' gedit
```

You can even make this default by modifying the file in `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop`. Though I don't recommend you to do so.

Comment: You are a star +1. I cloned my gedit.desktop to gedit-unity.desktop and changed the **Exec=gedit** to **Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='' gedit** and then added the modified application launcher to my top panel. I now get the cleaner looking interface. I have left the original desktop file untouched. 100% satisfaction. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad that it works!

Comment: Very weird ... just set up my second PC (my home machine) and I simply cannot replicate the Unity view.  Made *exactly* the same changes, but I still get the Gnome view. _/scratches head_. Not serious though as I have now fixed my Radiance Title Bar Display, and I have the Silver Grey view.